# How do I create responsive navigation using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive

I use a boostrap template (Dreamweaver) to create my websites. I want to edit the navigation menu by removing the border from the menu icon and change the position of the links. How can I achieve this?

Example: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIKDN.jpg

Menu Border: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH7Hf.jpg

Nav Links: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsE6A.jpg

```css
@charset "utf-8";
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
 margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
 padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
 background: #000000;
}

.logo {
 width: 100px;
 height: 25px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar {
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #151515;
 border-radius: 0px;
 border-color: #1a1919;
}

li {
 margin-right: 10px;
}



a {
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

a:hover {
 color: #5e5e5e !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
  
   <a href="index.html"> 
      <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="img/Logo White.png">
   </a>
   </div>
    
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
    list-style: none; /* removes the bubble */
    text-align: center; /* centers the text */
    margin-left: #; /*offsets the bubble placement a bit due to the li tag */
}
```

Personally, I use an individual div tag for list items and create the list myself for more manuverability; for instance, text-align: center; wouldn't need an offset.

For the button: Setting a seperate class on the button is not needed but can be effective for simplicities sake and then add

```
border: none; /*removes the border*/
```

Answer (score 0):

- For removing bubble from the menu list item you can use `list-style:
  none;` in the list.
- For positioning the list menu item to the center you can use `text-align: center;` in the list also.
- For removing the
  border from the menu icon you can use `text-decoration: none;` in the
  anchor.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
    html {
     position: relative;
     min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
     margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
     padding: 0;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #FFFFFF !important;
     background: #000000;
    }
    .logo {
     width: 100px;
     height: 25px;
     margin-top: 10px;
    }
.navbar {
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #151515;
     border-radius: 0px;
     border-color: #1a1919;
    }
    li {
     margin-right: 10px;
     list-style: none; /* removes the bubble */
     text-align: center; /* centers the text */
    }
    a {
     color: #FFFFFF !important;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
     color: #5e5e5e !important;
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid"> 
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        <a href="index.html"> 
      <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="img/Logo White.png">
        </a>
      </div>  
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
         <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi @Calvin, did you solve your problem? Is my answer help you? If my answer help you, then you can consider it as a correct answer.

Comment: It worked for the text, but it still shows a bubble. How do get a normal hamburger icon?

Comment: Can you share the link with me or Screenshot? @Calvin

Comment: Go through this link; https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/hamburger-menu/  here you will give lot's of example of humburger menu.